# How to make columns except first in each row to be align left?

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I want to make all columns except the first of a row in table to be `text-align:left`, the first column is `text-align` defined in CSS. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
table{
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td{
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("input[type='button']").on("click", function(){
        $("#table tr td:gt(0)").css({"text-align":"left"}); 
    });

});
</script>
 </head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="click" />
<table id="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td width="150px">center</td><td width="150">left</td><td width="150">left</td></tr>
        <tr><td>center</td><td>left</td><td>left</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>center</td><td>left</td><td>left</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

After I click the button, only the first row gets the effect, all columns of the other rows are all `text-left` including the first column which should not.
So why? Must I have to iterate `tr` elements with `each` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current jQuery code will get all `td`'s and then get the first of the collections... you have this collection of `td`'s then you get the first in that collection... that's what happened in you current code...

replace your code with this...

```
$(function(){
    $("input[type='button']").on("click", function(){
        $("#table tr td").not(':first-child').css({"text-align":"left"}); 
    });

});
```

and much better is if you could just use css....

```
table td{
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: left;
}

table td:first-child {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: thanks very much.  but you miss `:not`, the final code is like this: `$("#table tr td:not(:first-child)").css({"text-align":"left"})`

Comment: does `:first-child` selector supported broadly?

Answer (score 0):

Use `:not` or `.not()` and `:first`.

```
$('#table tr td:not(#table tr td:first)').css({"text-align":"left"});
```

**OR**

```
$('table tr td').not(':first').css({"text-align":"left"});
```

Comment: your code has the same effect with me: all `td`'s except the first of the first row are `left` which is not what I want. But thanks for reminding me to add `not`.

Comment: `:first` is just same as `.get(0)`

Comment: @HiwayChe i think you want.. `"I want to make all columns except the first of a row in table to be text-align:left"` tell me what is wrong with my answer..???

Comment: @Dipesh, hi, maybe I don't express my requirements clearly, sorry for my poor english. I want all `td`'s (the first `td` excluded) in every `tr` to be align left when I click `button`, you can see in my css, at the begining, all `td`'s are align center, so after clicking button, the first `td` should still be center, but the sibling `td`'s at the same `tr` should be left. I just run your code, after clicking button, only the first `tr` gets the effects I want, in the follwing `tr`'s, their `td`'s children are all left including the first `td`. I wish I explain it clearly. Thank you.